# Install Tomcat v7.0.32 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse Juno and Apache Tomcat 7.0.32, but I can't add my Tomcat in Eclipse. I have installed the JST Server Adapter Plug-in Developer Resources, but when I try to add my Tomcat doesn't appear an option for Apache Tomcat v7.0. But appear v6.0 and earlier.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the net. For instance check out this video. In the beginning the guy shows how to configure Tomcat in Eclipse: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ih-t9WAmM8

Comment: http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of WTP (Web Tools Platform) installed. It should bring Tomcat 7 straight away. It will even give you the option of downloading Tomcat directly from Eclipse (in your case you don't seem to need it, though)